# Creating a Web Resource Web Page that Calls a Web Resource Javascript CRM 2015

Tags: javascript, sdk, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I am using:

```js
/// <reference path="https://benelfakir.crm4.dynamics.com//WebResources/new_sdk_rest" />
```

But I get this message error

```
<Message>ReferenceError: SDK is not defined</Message>
```

that is my code

```js
/// <reference path="new_/Scripts/sdk_rest.js" />
function load() {
    var AccountId = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
    alert(AccountId);
    var account = {};
    account.Description = "Updated Account Name odata";
    SDK.REST.updateRecord(AccountId, account, "Account", "", errorHandler);
    alert("done");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you exactly call this method ? And is where is defined SDK ?

So this will not work with ribbon workbench.

```js
function SDK {
  //blablabla
}

function toCallFunction{
  SDK.blablabla();
}
```

If you want to do it you should do like this :

```js
function toCall(){
  function SDK(){
    //blablabla
  }
  SDK.blablabla();
}
```

Yes , I know, this is stupid way to resolve the solution. But you should copy and past the SDK into your function.

Comment: I call this method in button (ribbon ) and the sdk is a webresource that i had upload it

Comment: Are you using ribbon workbench, right ? If you using it, there is a problem when using a function. You can't reach other functions, if you want to use it just keep it in one function. So what I suggest is do it everything is one big function which has these functions.

Comment: yes ,I use ribbon workbench ! <br> can you tell me how can i resolve this "issue" ?? there is an other metode to call the webressource without using ribbon workbench ?